# SonarQube upgrade from 6.4 to 6.5 breaks the scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

1. I am on sonarQube6.4 and have upgraded to 6.5
2. Sonar-scanner is 3.0.3
3. Now after the upgrade the scanner fails anytime there is a java file in the source path. If I don't scan java files everything works just fine.
4. However If I rollback an use 6.4 version, everything works fine, so is there any regression? This is the stack trace, when I run the scanner command  with -X command. So is it a mandate in 6.5 to provided the location of all compiled classed, is there a way to ignore it.

> 04:56:21.218 DEBUG: Sensors : JavaSquidSensor -> SurefireSensor ->
>   JaCoCoSensor -> SonarJavaXmlFileSensor -> Analyzer for "php.ini" files
>   -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer 04:56:21.218 INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] 04:56:21.558 INFO: Configured Java source
>   version (sonar.java.source): none 04:56:21.565 INFO: JavaClasspath
>   initialization 04:56:21.570 INFO:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 04:56:21.571 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE 04:56:21.571 INFO:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 04:56:21.571 INFO: Total time: 6.545s 04:56:21.707 INFO: Final Memory:
>   51M/1083M 04:56:21.707 INFO:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 04:56:21.707 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled
>   classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
>           at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:59)
>           at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:281)
>           at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:141)
>           at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.(JavaSquid.java:83)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:83)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:179)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:256)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:245)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:119)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61) 04:56:21.710 DEBUG: Execution getVersion 04:56:21.711 DEBUG: Execution
>   stop

When I run the same with 6.4, it works fine and the only warning I see in the console is :

> 04:52:42.738 WARN: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property

Comment: The plugin version is important, seems your two SonarQube might run a different SonarJava version.

Comment: Agreed, in 6.4  it is sonar-java-plugin-4.9.0.9858.jar, while in 6.5 it is sonar-java-plugin-4.12.0.11033.jar, but still I believe this is a regression, where with the new plugin it is a mandate to provide the .class files location. I wish there is an option to override it

Answer (score 22):

> Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled
>   classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property

Since SonarJava 4.12, you must specify sonar.java.binaries property  https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode

Example :

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=fr.demo:my-project -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.java.binaries=.
```

Comment: what did you provide the java.binaries as for android project?

Comment: @Mrityunjeyan S : you can find an example here : https://android.jlelse.eu/sonarqube-code-coverage-for-kotlin-on-android-with-bitrise-71b2fee0b797
"sonar.sources=app/src/main/java"
"sonar.java.binaries=target/classes"
If you execute sonar-scanner, the arguments are "-Dsonar.sources=app/src/main/java" and "-Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes"
Adapt the path according to your own application path.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

```
Error during SonarQube Scanner execution org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException:
Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
```

It seems like the java sensor requires the `.class` files, in addition to the `.java` files.

You could:

- Add those files to the analysis (it will by the way give you more valuable sonar findings!)
- Try adding and removing files to find out, which piece of code causes the issue and report it as a Sonar Java bug

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. I agree, the analysis results would be more accurate with the bytecode access. However the fact is we don't version control the class files in GIT, so when we invoke this as a simple trigger with version control, there is no access to these .classes and hence it breaks now, unlike in 6.4

Comment: @PrashantSaddi Could you run the analysis on the same machine that runs the compilation of your code?

Comment: I am actually trying to use SQ as part of jenkins builds so it depends on how the users have setup their sonar properties. I am very sure they don't have this property, so requesting 100 different teams to make changes to their jobs might not be easy, so maybe we wait for a future version which allows the binaries location to be optional

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well and I fixed it in the following way:

[This page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/java) mentions about an entry which was optional before and became mandatory during the latest update (4.12). It says that the `sonar.java.binaries` entry in the Jenkins project settings should be set. When set, even to a faulty folder, it will fix your errors, leaving only a warning and your pipeline will be running again.

The setting should be added to Jenkins -> "your project" -> Configuration -> Build -> Execute SonarQube Scanner -> Analysis Properties. Add this entry and point it to your binaries folder.

Answer (score 0):

Even i was also facing same issue after **`SonarQube`** upgrade to latest 6.5 version. But after downgrading **`SonarJava`** plugin(from **4.12 to 4.11**), it worked. 
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that will solve the problem, since my SQ 6.4 does come with SonarJava4.9 and it worked just fine

Comment: @PrashantSaddi Yes i agree but after updating the plugin i faced the issue. But after downgrading it worked.