# SonarQube Scanner error when run "sonar-scanner" command

Tags: java, android, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, software-quality

I want to use sonarQube to analyze an android project. 
While I am trying to install  SonarQube Scanner, I have faced some problem.

I received the following error when running `sonar-scanner` command from the project directory.

*I have followed the Installation steps from this link https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

*I am using SonarQube 6.5 and SonarScanner 3.0.3

```
    ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
  org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled 
  classes of
  your project with sonar.java.binaries property
    at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:59)
    at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements (AbstractJavaClasspath.java:281)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:
  141)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.<init>(JavaSquid.java:83)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:8
   3)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)

    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java
  :82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java
 :68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseE
 xecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanCon
 tainer.java:179)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
ontainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
    .java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer
.java:261)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectSc
anContainer.java:256)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanC
     ontainer.java:245)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
      ontainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
      .java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:
       84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
      ontainer.java:144)
    at 



       org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainerjava:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContain
         er.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.exec
        ute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
       java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(Iso
        latedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner
     .java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScann
      er.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
   ERROR:
   ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug 
 logging
```

.

If you have any solution for this problem, please help me.

Comment: What about the error message is unclear to you?

Comment: Yes the error message is not clear. I do not understand what I have to do?     - @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: "Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property"

Comment: Where can I find sonar.java.binaries? @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781904/sonarqube-upgrade-from-6-4-to-6-5-breaks-the-scanner) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube upgrade from 6.4 to 6.5 breaks the scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781904/sonarqube-upgrade-from-6-4-to-6-5-breaks-the-scanner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your project before the analysis. Let's say that your project structure is equal to:

```
project
|- src
|- dependencies
|- classes
```

then you should configure:

```
sonar.sources = src
sonar.java.libraries = dependencies/**/*.jar
sonar.java.binaries = classes
```

Read more at: [Java Plugin and Bytecode](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode)